# Excluding an element from a hover action

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors

I have a list in the navbar and all items (both "Home" and "Why") are subject to a hover action in the css:

```css
#main-nav .nav a,
#main-nav .nav a:active,
#main-nav .nav a:hover {
  opacity:0.5;
  -webkit-transition:opacity 0.2s ease-out;
  transition:opacity 0.2s ease-out; 
}

#main-nav .nav .active > a,
#main-nav .nav a:hover {
  opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<div id="site-nav" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li>
      <a href="#home" class="scrollto">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#about" class="scrollto">Why</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The hover action makes the text be at default in 0.5 opacity, and it turns to 1 opacity when you hover over it.

How can I exclude one of the A HREF items from this opacity action, while remaining in the same place of the html code for reasons of styling, position, etc?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Which <a> do you want to exclude? First, last, random?

Comment: The second <a>. I just want it to stay at 1 opacity all the time.

Comment: No element has `class` set to `"active"` at HTML at Question

Answer (score 1):

One way is to combine `not()` and `nth-child` (on `li`, won't work on `a`):

EDIT after comment: If you want the initial state not to apply and the hover state already is what you want for the second child all the time, it should be this way (that way also `hover` won't apply to the second link):

EDITED one more time to make it a more realistic situation (`:active` and `:hover` only apply to the second rule, wouldn't make sense on the first one):

```
#main-nav .nav li:not(:nth-child(2)) a {
  opacity:0.5;
  -webkit-transition:opacity 0.2s ease-out;
  transition:opacity 0.2s ease-out; 
  }

#main-nav .nav li:not(:nth-child(2)) a:active,
#main-nav .nav li:not(:nth-child(2)) a:hover{
  opacity:1;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use :not selector
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_not.asp

```
#main-nav .nav a:hover:not(.someclass){
   opacity:0.5;
}
```

```css
#site-nav .nav a,
#site-nav .nav a:active,
#site-nav .nav a:hover{
  opacity:0.2;
  }

#site-nav .nav .active > a,
#site-nav .nav a:hover:not(.normal){
  opacity:1;
  }
```

```html
<div id="site-nav" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>
            <a href="#home" class="scrollto normal">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#about" class="scrollto">Why</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried adding class="xx" to one of the a ref items and then adding :not(.xx) to the hover action but it didn't work for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare `opacity: 1` for

- `li a:hover`

you can, at the same time, declare `opacity: 1` for

- `li a[href="#about"]`

**Working Example:**

```css
li a {
opacity: 0.5;
transition: opacity 0.2s ease-out; 
}

li a:hover, li a[href="#about"] {
opacity: 1; 
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li><a href="#home" class="scrollto">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#about" class="scrollto">Why</a></li>
</ul>
```